# In Bokeh, how can I display different information for points and patches?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to display different information for different layers (points and patches) using `bokeh`.

I downloaded the shapefile and the population information of Haitian cities respectively from [here](https://data.world/ocha-haiti/777e8b06-337f-4295-80bc-ca1515244215) and from [here](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/estimated-population-of-haiti-2015/resource/ef7b909d-6dee-45dd-b7d7-6dc6c80eb49f) and I merged them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import osmnx as ox

from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure, save
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df


from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import LogColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment import data as unemployment

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=palette)
```

Some functions

```
 def getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
        """Returns the coordinates ('x' or 'y') of edges of a Polygon exterior"""

        # Parse the exterior of the coordinate
        exterior = row[geom].exterior

        if coord_type == 'x':
            # Get the x coordinates of the exterior
            return list( exterior.coords.xy[0] )
        elif coord_type == 'y':
            # Get the y coordinates of the exterior
            return list( exterior.coords.xy[1] )
def getPointCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """Calculates coordinates ('x' or 'y') of a Point geometry"""
    if coord_type == 'x':
        return row[geom].x
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        return row[geom].y
```

Cities data

```
haiti = gpd.read_file(hti_admbnda_adm2_cnigs_20181129.shp')
haiti = haiti.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32618'})
haiti = haiti[haiti.index != 98].reset_index(drop=True) ## i=98 is corrupted

pop = pd.read_csv('hti_admnbnda_adm2_cnigs2013c.csv')
level = 2
left = 'adm%dcode'%level
right = 'ADM%d_PCODE'%level
h_geom = pd.merge(pop, haiti, left_on=left, right_on=right)
```

Then I created a data for `bokeh`

```
grid = pd.DataFrame()
grid['x'] = h_geom.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
grid['y'] = h_geom.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)
grid['Name'] = h_geom['adm2_en']
grid['Population'] = h_geom['TOTAL']
data=dict(
    x=list(grid['x'].values),
    y=list(grid['y'].values),
    name=list(grid['Name'].values),
    rate=list(grid['Population'].values),
)
```

From `osmnx` I get points of schools

```
selected_amenities = ['school']
place = 'Haiti'
schoolOSM = ox.pois_from_place(place=place, amenities=selected_amenities)
schools = gpd.GeoDataFrame(schoolOSM)
idxok = []
for i in schools.index:
    if type(schools['geometry'][i]) == shapely.geometry.point.Point:
        idxok.append(i)
schools = schools[schools.index.isin(idxok)]
schools['x'] = schools.apply(getPointCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
schools['y'] = schools.apply(getPointCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)

data1=dict(
    x=list(schools['x'].values),
    y=list(schools['y'].values),
)
```

Then I want to show the information: I would like to show Name, Population and coordinates for cities while only coordinates for schools.

```
TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,save"

p = figure(title="Schools Point in Haiti", tools=TOOLS,
    x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None,
    tooltips=[("Name", "@name"), ("Population", "@rate"), ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)")])

p.hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
p.patches('x', 'y', source=data,
         fill_color={'field': 'rate', 'transform': color_mapper},
         fill_alpha=1.0, line_color="black", line_width=1)
# Add points on top (as black points)
p.circle('x', 'y', size=3, source=data1, color="black")

show(p)
```

In doing so I get the information of `Name`, `Population`, `Long`, `Lat` for both Schools and Cities. But Schools do not have the info `Name` and `Population`, so I get something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two separate data sources and two separate HoverTools.

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

data_cities = dict(x = list(cities['x'].values),  y = list(cities['y'].values))
data_schools = dict(x = list(schools['x'].values),  y = list(schools['y'].values))

cities = p.circle('x', 'y', size = 3, source = data_cities, color = "green")
schools = p.circle('x', 'y', size = 3, source = data_schools, color = "blue")

hover_cities = HoverTool(renderers = [cities], tooltips = [("Name", "@name"), ("Population", "@rate"), ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)")]))
hover_schools = HoverTool(renderers = [schools], tooltips = [("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)")]))

p.add_tools(hover_cities)
p.add_tools(hover_schools)
```

Comment: sounds good, however my cities are patches. I changed the point policy and set for both `point_policy="follow_mouse"`. However when I am over a point the two information overlap. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: then you replace `cities = p.circle()` with `cities = p.patches()`

Comment: Yes I did it, my problem now is that there are some overlap between the information when I pass the mouse.

Comment: make sure you remove `hover` from the `TOOLS` string in `figure` constructor (`TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,reset,save"`)